# Apply jQuery UI easing animation to add/removeClass

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, animation

I'm trying to create a 'sticky header' - that is once you scroll past X amount, the header becomes fixed.

Got this working, see JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8vjo8t6p/1/

However I want to add a little animation to make it smoother. I am using jQuery UI however I am not getting the proper smooth "swing" animation, it's still just snapping into place.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    // Creates sticky header 
    var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
    var scroll_pos_test = 290;
    if(y_scroll_pos >= scroll_pos_test) {
        $("#home-table .head").addClass("sticky-header", 800, "swing" );
    }else if(y_scroll_pos < 290){
        $("#home-table .head").removeClass("sticky-header", 800, "swing" );
    }
});
```

Comment: You could try using CSS3 transitions. This might be helpful: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2014/05/how-to-create-an-animated-sticky-header-with-css3-and-jquery/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The docu says: "Adds the specified class(es) to each of the set of matched elements while animating all style changes." http://api.jqueryui.com/addclass/

Comment: @Francesca my apologies, I'll shut my hole. I didn't know jQueryUI did that :D

Comment: @ReLeaf That was my original plan however I needed to add the transition to the `.head` class because it needs to be adding to the existing class. I could not get it to work with my newly added class of `.sticky-header`

Comment: jQueryUI is not working on your fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/8vjo8t6p/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/8vjo8t6p/2/)

Comment: ^ That. Also, I'm reasonably sure jqueryui can't meaningfully animate `position`